# Performing aggregate sum on custom class IQueryable(Of T)

Tags: vb.net, linq

I've been trying to perform sum on vb.net using LINQ on a IQueryable of a custom class Aggregate_Table that I defined below. I'm not sure how to achieve this as the usual sum function gives me syntax error when applied to the IQueryable(Of T) of my custom class.

I started with the following query :

```
Dim initial_SIs = From si In database._58k_SIs
                      Group By si.From_Firm, si.From_Account_Number, si.To_Account_Number, si.To_Firm, si.Security_Code, si.Settlement_Ccy
                   Into Quantity = Sum(si.Quantity), Settlement_Amount = Sum(si.Settlement_Amount)
```

Which is a simple query from table _58k_SIs in datacontext object database. Since the type for this query result is anonymous data type, and I will need to create a function that takes in a specific table type, I went on to create a class name Aggregate_SI with the same attributes as the query result above .(Each of the attribute of this class has their own corresponding property that I omitted for brevity)

```
 Public Class Aggregated_SI
   Private _From_Firm As String
   Private _From_Account_Number As String
   Private _To_Account_Number As String
   Private _To_Firm As String
   Private _Security_Code As String
   Private _Quantity As Integer
   Private _Settlement_Amount As Decimal
   Private _Settlement_Ccy As String

   Public Property Quantity
    Get
        Return _Quantity
    End Get
    Set(value)
        _Quantity = value
    End Set
    End Property
 End Class
```

I created a list of Aggregated_SI object and transfer all the query result to that list since list(Of T) object can be used for LINQ query.

```
Dim test_List = New List(Of Aggregated_SI)
    For Each si In initial_SIs
        test_List.Add(New Aggregated_SI(si.From_Firm, si.From_Account_Number, si.To_Account_Number, si.To_Firm, si.Security_Code, si.Quantity, si.Settlement_Amount, si.Settlement_Ccy))
    Next
```

The aggregation :

```
Dim outflow = From si In test_List
                  Group By si.From_Account_Number, si.Security_Code
                  Into Total_outflow = Sum(si.Quantity)
```

gives me an error message

```
 Error  BC36594 Definition of method 'Sum' is not accessible in this context.   

        Error   BC30519 Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Sum' can be called without a narrowing conversion:
Extension method 'Public Function Sum(selector As Func(Of Aggregated_SI, Integer)) As Integer' defined in 'Enumerable': Return type of nested function matching parameter 'selector' narrows from 'Object' to 'Integer'.
Extension method 'Public Function Sum(selector As Func(Of Aggregated_SI, Integer?)) As Integer?' defined in 'Enumerable': Return type of nested function matching parameter 'selector' narrows from 'Object' to 'Integer?'.
Extension method 'Public Function Sum(selector As Func(Of Aggregated_SI, Long)) As Long' defined in 'Enumerable': Return type of nested function matching parameter 'selector' narrows from 'Object' to 'Long'.
Extension method 'Public Function Sum(selector As Func(Of Aggregated_SI, Long?)) As Long?' defined in 'Enumerable': Return type of nested function matching parameter 'selector' narrows from 'Object' to 'Long?'.
Extension method 'Public Function Sum(selector As Func(Of Aggregated_SI, Single)) As Single' defined in 'Enumerable': Return type of nested function matching parameter 'selector' narrows from 'Object' to 'Single'.
Extension method 'Public Function Sum(selector As Func(Of Aggregated_SI, Single?)) As Single?' defined in 'Enumerable': Return type of nested function matching parameter 'selector' narrows from 'Object' to 'Single?'.
Extension method 'Public Function Sum(selector As Func(Of Aggregated_SI, Double)) As Double' defined in 'Enumerable': Return type of nested function matching parameter 'selector' narrows from 'Object' to 'Double'.
Extension method 'Public Function Sum(selector As Func(Of Aggregated_SI, Double?)) As Double?' defined in 'Enumerable': Return type of nested function matching parameter 'selector' narrows from 'Object' to 'Double?'.
Extension method 'Public Function Sum(selector As Func(Of Aggregated_SI, Decimal)) As Decimal' defined in 'Enumerable': Return type of nested function matching parameter 'selector' narrows from 'Object' to 'Decimal'.
Extension method 'Public Function Sum(selector As Func(Of Aggregated_SI, Decimal?)) As Decimal?' defined in 'Enumerable': Return type of nested function matching parameter 'selector' narrows from 'Object' to 'Decimal?'. Settlement_Optimisation C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\WindowsApplication1\Form1.vb    22  Active
```

I've been trying to work around this problem for a few hours without avail. Anyone has any suggestion on how can I approach this problem?

Comment: Please include the full definition of Aggregated_SI class. You have only included the field declarations (private) but you are apparently using the property Quantity and you don't show its definition. From the error I assume that Quantity property returns an object instead of Integer.

Comment: I've included the quantity property and the rest of the field is more or less the same. Will it help if I include everything? I'm just afraid that it will be too long because it's just the repetition of the properties and one constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've declared the Quantity property as `Public Property Quantity` instead of `Public Property Quantity As Integer`. This causes Quantity to cast the result to object and there is no Sum() extension that can summarize objects. Use the proper return type and it should work:

```
Public Class Aggregated_SI
   Private _From_Firm As String
   Private _From_Account_Number As String
   Private _To_Account_Number As String
   Private _To_Firm As String
   Private _Security_Code As String
   Private _Quantity As Integer
   Private _Settlement_Amount As Decimal
   Private _Settlement_Ccy As String

   Public Property Quantity As Integer
    Get
        Return _Quantity
    End Get
    Set(value As Integer)
        _Quantity = value
    End Set
    End Property
 End Class
```

PS: it's been a long time since I wrote VB.Net, I am not sure about including the type in the setter's value parameter, but you can remove it if compiler complains

Comment: Oh my, I made such a basic mistake. Thanks for the help! By the way you're correct in including the type in the setter's value parameter